# Is it allowed to cast from struct to char pointer and back for the purposes of pointer arithmetic?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, pointer-arithmetic

Consider the following struct:

```
struct s {
  int a, b;
};
```

Given a pointer to this structure, `struct s *p`, you could increment the pointer to point to the next `s` as follows:

```
struct s *next(struct s *p) {
  return p + 1;
}
```

Is the following equivalent and legal:

```
struct s *nextc(struct s *p) {
  char *pc = (char *)p;
  return (struct s *)(pc + sizeof(struct s));
}
```

If any assumption about the value of `alignof(struct s)` is necessary for your answer, please mention it.

Comment: When you say "next" you're talking specifically about arrays, right?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli - it could be an array, or perhaps a region of memory allocated by `malloc()`, or a suitably aligned pointer into an array of `char`, or... I tried to sidestep this question by comparing it to the usual way of incrementing, i.e., asking "if `p + 1` is valid, is `pc + sizeof(struct s)` valid?", rather than describing what exactly `p` points to, since I think that sidesteps a lot of issues.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli - that said, if `next` and `nextc` are equivalent in some cases, but not in others, depending on the nature of `p` then that would be a really interesting answer (and means my attempted simplification failed...).

Comment: I think they must be equivalent, otherwise it'd be impossible to write `qsort` and `bsearch` correctly.  I can't find the relevant passage in the standard, though.

Comment: 6.5.6 footnote 108 seems to justify this, but I feel like there ought to be something in the main text.

Comment: @NateEldredge - right, although some would claim that as library functions they can use undocumented magic outside the standard (i.e., _you_ or _I_ couldn't write those functions in standard C, but the standard library itself may rely on additional guarantees provided by the target compilers, or something like that...).

Comment: Indeed.  What I mean is that I'm fairly sure you're supposed to be able to write your own functions along the same lines.

Comment: @NateEldredge - in [this version](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6) you are talking about footnote 106, right? Indeed, it actually explains T* arithmetic _in terms of_ `char *` arithmetic, implying that the char arithmetic was valid in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that's the one.  108 in [this version](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf).